# Vertical Histogram in Excel with Conditional Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts, conditional-formatting

I'm able to do data bar conditional formatting in Excel 2010, but I can't figure out how to switch the bar axis to make it vertical. Is there any way around this? Can I simulate a vertical histogram with conditional formatting?

Comment: Two questions:  do you want to switch from a bar chart to a column chart?  Also, what do you mean by conditional formatting, within the chart itself?

Comment: Yes, switch from bar to column chart. I mean that I am trying to have each cell have one bar based on its value. I am using Conditional Formatting > Data Bars option to generate the bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data bars in conditional formatting are Left-Right or Right-Left only. There's no Up-Down or Down-Up option available.

The only way to get a vertical data bar-type look would be to use a formula and change the Fill settings to a gradient, but you don't get enough control over the gradient to differentiate the different values.

Another option is to [spark lines](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2009/07/17/sparklines-in-excel.aspx). There's a nice example of something that might do what you want here: http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2009/07/22/formatting-sparklines.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I was interested in something similar and was able to achieve it. Though I didn't use conditional formatting, I think this example will show you how to achieve what you want.

1. Put the numbers 1,2,3,2,1 in cells b2 through f2.
2. Put the formula `=REPT("|",B2)` in cell b4 and copy through f4.
3. Change the text direction to go up.

That's achieves the outcome but to make it look nice you'll want to center the cells and adjust cell width and height.

It should look like this:
 
[image: image of in cell graph]

If you don't like the spaces between the lines switch the font to playbill and you'll see a normal bar graph with no spaces.

This does what you want without conditional formatting. You may want to add some conditional formatting if you want to vary the color of the bar graphs or something else.

Comment: Well, not what I was looking for, but nice trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the conditional formatting in Excel to create a column chart instead of a bar chart.  This conditional formatting isn't creating a true Chart object in Excel, so you don't have the same flexibility in modifying its appearance.

Instead, you can create a `Column Chart` by selecting your data and `Insert > Column` (and choose your subtype).  Then you can format the Chart in any manner you prefer.

**EDIT:**  Based upon your notes, and borrowing from @Rhys Gibson, here's a solution using sparklines (which are available in Excel 2010, or add-ins pre-Excel 2010).  I've included both the conditional formating bar charts (nearly impossible to make sense of), and their sparkline equivalents.

[image]

**EDIT:**  One other point that may seem relatively minor, a Histogram is not a Column (or Bar) chart.  They are distinctly (if subtly) different chart types and the terminology shouldn't be interchanged.  For a great description of the difference, check out Naomi Robbins' [A Histogram is not a Bar Chart](http://www.forbes.com/sites/naomirobbins/2012/01/04/a-histogram-is-not-a-bar-chart/)

Comment: I have 200 rows of data and want a small histogram for each of them - not going to create 200 column charts - and I am well aware of how to create a column chart. The question was, can this be done with conditional formatting? I have seen hints elsewhere that there may be a workaround to make this work. Can you confirm that this is not possible?

Comment: You can't do what you're looking for with conditional formatting. Based on your info in the above comment, I think you want sparkline column charts like @rhys gibson suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Transpose the table.
2. Rotate text down.
3. Conditional formating > Data bars (as you wish)
4. Copy table and paste as Picture
5. Rotate Picture.

[IMAGE - CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6qtY.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the data can be arranged horizontally, to fake Conditional Formatting Data Bars that are vertical, use the camera tool to take an image of the column with the Data Bars and rotate that image, that way the image will update with new values. The width of the image can be adjusted to match same sized columns and placed under the row(s) that contains the other data. May want to unlock aspect ratio in the "Format Picture" options when resizing.
Downside is if another column is added, the camera image will need to be retaken, and expect very wide tables if you have 200 items across and do not rotate the text!

Answer (score 0):

Thats what I was looking for:

https://a4accounting.com.au/horizontal-or-vertical-progress-bar-in-excel/

[Click me (=> Sorry, I'm not allowed to post images yet.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpOYg.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).